# I want to testfor if there is specific player in a specific team

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Its for my adventure map
basically an anti-cheat mechanic that makes sure anyone that isn't me can't join the team "Admin"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `team` selector argument to test for people on a specific team, and the `name` selector to test for a specific player:

```
/testfor @a[name=PlayerName,team=Admin]
```